# Thymeleaf shows null on form when using th:field?

Tags: thymeleaf

Using Spring with Thymeleaf (spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf) current version. When I have a form where some fields are null, Thymeleaf is showing null in the input control. How do I make it just show blank?

This is only happening when I use fetch and replace a div. If I open a window from the URL the content is fine. What's happening?

TIA

```
<label for="address1">Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" th:field="*{address1}"> <br>

<label for="address2">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" th:field="*{address2}"> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I realized I had some binding code that wasn't checking for that.

Comment: What was the issue with the binding code?

Comment: @code I can't remember it might have been something misspelled rather than a value being null.